# Rails 4 Migration: Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'xx'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, limit

Here is the migration:

```
create_table "address", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "street_number",       limit: 10
    t.string   "street_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Now in the console:

```
a = Address.new({street_number: '57', street_name: 'Allen Ave'})
a.save

(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'street_number'
```

The limit on **street_number** is **10 characters**

when attempting to **save 2 charaters** we get the **Mysql2::Error:**

**Data too long for column**

Comment: Check in `db/schema.rb` that the `street_number` does have `limit: 10`; it might be that a previous migration had incorrectly set the limit as `1` and the new migration has not been applied yet.

Comment: I tested that theory by attempting to save a single character to the record.  Still received Msql2::Error: Data too long for column.  It's weird.

Comment: What's in the db/schema.rb file?